# Mysql encoding breaks after restarting the application

Tags: mysql, jsf-2, openshift

When I restart the openshift application using command `ctl_app restart` my database encoding breaks. For example, before restart in database I've got text 'jabłko' but after restart it's 'jab?ko'. How can I fix it? Application was created using jsf2 + mysql.

Comment: How do yo make it go away after restarting?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. Can you ask more clearly?

Comment: How do you normally start it? Character set was explicit set?

Comment: How do I start it? Openshift controlls all of it. Openshift starts application and mysql after `git push`. I don't need to do nothing. If I manually restart app using command `ctl_app restart` or openshift will do that on `git push`, mysql encoding breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fix it. All I needed to do was to change mysql server encoding to utf8 by adding this to my.conf.

```
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
```

to `mysqld` section

Comment: in what folder ? ~/mysql/conf ? and what did you after adding these two lines to mysqld section? Did you restart Mysql? How?